# User can able to Cancel the download of force Install Applications

Tags: android-management-api

When We apply a policy with applications which have [install Type](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#InstallType) as FORCE_INSTALLED.

So user Can't able to remove the app from device.

But When Policy Apply to the Device, Application stated to download.
At that time user can able to cancel the download.
So application not get installed in device.

Is there any way to restrict this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to prevent cancelling the installation of the app on the device. FORCE_INSTALLED is an install type that will ensure that an app will start installation upon provisioning and once installed successfully, the user will not be able to remove it.

If it is really important that the app will be installed successfully into the device, you can set the [installType](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#InstallType) to REQUIRED_FOR_SETUP. This install type allows the app to automatically install during device provisioning. Provisioning will fail if the app was not installed successfully and also prevents the user from removing the app.